# Apache Thrift Javascript client to C++ Server

Tags: javascript, c++, thrift

I am having problems writing a Javascript client that interacts with a C++ server. I know Javascript only accepts JSON so I thought that if all I had to do was change the server protocol to JSON I thought it might work but its not. I am getting a weird error. I am using Firefox to run the Javascript client with http://localhost:9090/hello.html

error:

```
    Thrift: Mon Jun 15 16:54:07 2015 TSimpleServer exception: N6apache6thrift8protocol18TProtocolExceptionE: Expected '['; got 'G'.
```

Javascript Client

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- Simple Apache Thrift Client -->
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello Thrift</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        Name: 
        <input type="text" id="name_in">
        <input type="button" id="get_msg" value="Get Message" >
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script src="bower_components/thrift/lib/js/src/thrift.js"></script>
        <script src="gen-js/helloSvc.js"></script>
        <script>
          (function() {
            <!-- Setup Apache Thrift Client -->
            var transport = new Thrift.Transport("/nodejs/hello");
            var protocol  = new Thrift.Protocol(transport);
            var client    = new helloSvcClient(protocol);
            <!-- Wire Apache Thrift RPC to DOM Click Event -->
            var nameElement = document.getElementById("name_in");
            var outputElement = document.getElementById("output");
            document.getElementById("get_msg")
              .addEventListener("click", function(){
                outputElement.innerHTML = client.getMessage(nameElement.value);
              });
          })();
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

C++ Server

```
    #include "helloSvc.h"
    #include <thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
    #include <thrift/protocol/TJSONProtocol.h>
    #include <thrift/server/TSimpleServer.h>
    #include <thrift/transport/TServerSocket.h>
    #include <thrift/transport/TBufferTransports.h>
    #include <thrift/server/TThreadedServer.h>
    #include <thrift/transport/TTransport.h>

    using namespace ::apache::thrift;
    using namespace ::apache::thrift::protocol;
    using namespace ::apache::thrift::transport;
    using namespace ::apache::thrift::server;

    using boost::shared_ptr;

    class helloSvcHandler : virtual public helloSvcIf {
     public:
      helloSvcHandler() {
        // Your initialization goes here
      }

      void getMessage(std::string& _return, const std::string& name) {
        // Your implementation goes here
        printf("getMessage\n");
            std::cout<<name<<std::endl;
            _return = "Hello from server";
      }

    };

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      int port = 9090;
      shared_ptr<helloSvcHandler> handler(new helloSvcHandler());
      shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new helloSvcProcessor(handler));
      shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
      shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
      shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TJSONProtocolFactory());
      TSimpleServer server(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
      std::cout<<"Starting server"<<std::endl;
      server.serve();
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30674536/499466). In short, the JavaScript client also wants a HTTP server. Aside from that: Are you sure that `<!--` these `-->` are valid comments within JavaScript code?

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter by accident for the above comment here is the full response:I saw that page. I am not sure if that would fixed the problem because I believe Python and Java have some sort of http server that you can instantiate on the spot. On the C++ side it has Http Transports (thrift_folder/lib/cpp/src/thrift/transport) not servers and I am not sure how to use the transports to start up a http c++ server.  I tried some stuff but I get errors. `<!-- these -->` are html tags. I just embeded the javascript into an html so I can just run it from firefox.

Comment: "*I am not sure if that would fixed the problem*"- I suggest to just try it. What I wrote over there is still true, regardless of the exact language. There is a Socket transport, and there is a HTTP transport in Thrift. Both are entirely different animals, they are not compatible with each other. If you have a client that is restricted to HTTP transport, you need to set up HTTP transport on the server side. You may want to look at the Thrift test suite implementation if still in doubt.

Comment: Hey JensG. I finally got it. I really appreciate all of your help. I didn't know about the test suite. that help out a lot. what ended up working was instead of typing in the address bar of firefox "http:localhost:9090" i went to file then open the html file and then it started working. Thanks